# Matlab multidimensional scatter

Tags: matlab, graph, matlab-figure, scatter-plot

I have a an nx4 matrix where each row is an observation.

The three three columsn represent by variables, and the fourth a 'fitness' parameter.

I would like to show this in a 3D scatter plot, where each axis is one of my variables and then color each point depending on how close to one of the extremes in my fourth column it is.

For example, say fitness ranged between 0 and 1. I would want observations with fintess 0 to be blue, those with fitness 1 to be red and those in-between some corresponding shade.

Any advice on how best to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `scatter3` has a color input argument. But you need to define the size of the markers also.

```
% Generate example data,
X=rand(10,1)*10;
Y=rand(10,1)*3;
Z=rand(10,1)*5;
fit=rand(10,1)*3+10;

scatter3(X,Y,Z,ones(size(X))*40,fit,'fill')
```

[image]

Comment: Good idea to use `'fill'`!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`scatter3`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) with an appropriate colormap:

```
scatter3(data(:,1), data(:,2), data(:,3), 10, data(:,4), '*')
colormap(hsv)
colorbar
```

where

- `data` is your matrix
- `10` is markersize
- `'*'` is the marker shape
- `hsv` is the selected colormap